# HQL error in named query subselect

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

This HQL results in the tremendously helpful "error in named query" message

```
    "FROM courseform c WHERE c.application.application IN 
(SELECT a.application FROM application a WHERE a.applicant=: applicant)"
```

The CourseForm has a OneToOne unidirectional relationship with the Application (this could potentially be made bidirectional if it would help). Application in turn has the same unidirectional OneToOne relationship with the Applicant. One applicant can have many applications.

Here are the (abridged) definitions

**CourseForm**

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ 
                @NamedQuery(name = "CourseForm.findByApplicant",
 query = "FROM courseform c WHERE c.application.application IN 
(SELECT a.application FROM application a WHERE a.applicant=: applicant)") })
public class CourseForm implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
long id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Career career;
private String academicPlan;
private String courseName;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ModeOfAttendance modeOfAttendance;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "application_fk")
    private Application application;
...
}
```

**Application**

```
@Entity
public class Application implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
long applicationNumber;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "applicant_fk")
private Applicant applicant;

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
private LocalDateTime lastUpdate = LocalDateTime.now();
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
private LocalDateTime submitted = null;

public Application() {
}
```

**Applicant**

```
@Entity
    @NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Applicant.findByApplicantID", 
query = "FROM Applicant a WHERE a.applicantID= :applicantID") })
public class Applicant implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7210042752148566673L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;
    private String applicantID;

    Applicant() {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, according to Mark, right answer is

```
 FROM courseform c WHERE c.application.applicant =: applicant
```

Comment: I also referenced the column name in the CourseForm to Application relationship, and made Application to Applicant a ManyToOne relationship, also referencing the column name.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is with `FROM courseform c WHERE c.application.application`.You have used `c.application.application` in `where` clause
It should be `FROM courseform c WHERE c.application`

Comment: That may be so but it isn't the only problem - the same error is visible if I make this change.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to:

```
FROM courseform c WHERE c.application.applicationNumber IN (SELECT a.applicationNumber FROM application a WHERE a.applicant=: applicant)
```

Comment: I can, but it doesn't make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: I can't see how that will help much, but here's a bit 
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: CourseForm.findByApplicant
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:526)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1743)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
 ... 57 more

Comment: maybe this works:

FROM courseform c WHERE c.application.applicant =: applicant

Comment: You have it right, make it an answer and I will accept it. Thank you. I also changed some of the mappings to make them more realistic but this was the HQL I ended up with